# UIPopoverController modal issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, uipopover

[image]

I have UIPopoverController

```
    UINavigationController *navVC = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC] autorelease];

    navVC.modalInPopover = YES;
    navVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;    


    _popoverLoginVC = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navVC];
```

And when I present popover

```
  [self.popoverLoginVC presentPopoverFromRect:centerFrame
                                     inView:self.splitVC.view
                   permittedArrowDirections:0 
                                   animated:YES];
```

**It looks like it is modal (I can't close popover by tapping outside) but other area hadn't dimmed.**
I have played with modalPresentationStyle with no luck (

Please, advise

Comment: So I need get result like screenshot

Comment: Why did you leave out the code for "presentPopoverFromRect"? It could be the key to solving your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line

> navVC.modalInPopover = YES;
>
> navVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

Comment: No, I need modal. The problem is - other area not dimmed

Comment: change the alpha of the mainview when you add popover on the view.

Answer (score 0):

It's modal because you're setting it to be modal.

```
navVC.modalInPopover = YES;
```

Just delete that and you should be fine if I understand you correctly.

Comment: No, I need modal, but **other area should be dimmed**

Answer (score 0):

A popover isn't meant to (and can't be specified to) dim the 'background' views, even if presented modally.

Comment: In iOS7 they actually do, automatically: "The popover content is layered on top of your existing content and the background is dimmed automatically", from the [reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
permittedArrowDirections:0
```

This is not a valid value for this parameter and will result in undefined behavior (at least in iOS >= 6). You must specify one of:

```
UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp = 1UL << 0,
UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown = 1UL << 1,
UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft = 1UL << 2,
UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight = 1UL << 3,
UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown | UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight,
```

Unfortunately, "no arrow" is not a supported option. :(